# jQuery UI autcomplete width problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I haven't touched anything from jQuery UI them and the width is bigger than my input. You can show what happens here: http://i54.tinypic.com/nqa107.jpg

How I can solve this? What parts of code do you need? The string are not more that 15 chars.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only recently switched to jQuery, so I might be wrong. It looks like you haven't grabbed one of the ui-themed stylesheets. Head to the jQuery UI [download page](http://jqueryui.com/download/), download the ui and use the stylesheet it generates for you. If you're happy with the way you have the ui working already, then you can discard the javascripts it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you have a rule that is specifying a width of 1401 pixels. Find that in your CSS stylesheets and remove or correct it. possibly change it to 16em if your strings are always 15 characters long?